# How can I get value from sequelize associated model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I still trying to get **menu_title** from associated Menu model to json. If I use below described code console shows me error
`ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'Products.MenuId' in 'field list'` also if I have defined `{foreignKey: 'menu_id'}`. What I'm doing wrong?

**Menu model:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
  var Menu = sequelize.define("Menu", {
      owner_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      menu_title: Sequelize.STRING,
  }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          Menu.hasMany(models.Product)
        }
      }
  });
  return Menu;
};
```

**Product model:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
  var Product = sequelize.define("Product", {
      owner_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      menu_id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      product_title: Sequelize.STRING,
  }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          Product.belongsTo(models.Menu, { foreignKey: 'menu_id'})
        }
      }
  });
  return Product;
};
```

**Then inside controller:**

```
Menu.find({
    where: { owner_id: req.user.id },
    include: [
        { model: Product }
    ]
}).success(function(match) {
    res.json(match.home);
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the foreign key on both sides of the relation

```
Menu.hasMany(models.Product, { foreignKey: 'menu_id'})
```

Otherwise sequelize assumes that the foreign key is called menuId when querying from the menu side of the relation

Comment: Hi Jan Aagaard, could you please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542461/sequelize-belongsto-not-adding-foreign-key-constraints-to-database-table